# UIWebview becomes blank(white) on tap of input tag - iOS 8.0 and 9.0

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs, uiwebview

I am loading a html inside UIWebView and using ionic, angular stuff inside the html and at some places I am bound to use Iframe to load a html inside it.
Everything works fine but only on iOS8.0 and above tapping on input field inside the webview makes the keyboard to popup and the entire webpage becomes blank.Only the UI becomes white but tapping anywhere inside the page makes you to the next screen.

```
<ion-header-bar title="titleName">
<iframe iframe-set-dimentions-onload width="100%" ng-src="locationTomyHtml" onLoad="htmlLoad()" id="iFrame"></iframe>
</ion-header-bar>
```

Is there a problem because of the iframe since the header remains static.
Can anyone help on this issue?